# Quill Editor Alphabetic List

Tags: javascript, quill, alphabet

Is there anybody that already got an alphabetic list working on Quill Editor?

For now you can only List with numeric
1.
2.
3.

I need :
a.
b.
c.

I could replace with JS but thats not the cleanest thing.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Quill defines its list styling [in CSS](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/8eeed058c5e297ba19ca1de933b71978b9c5dfa0/assets/core.styl#L3), which you can override yourself by setting a different [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type):

```css
.ql-editor ol li::before {
  content: counter(list-0, lower-alpha) '. ';
}
```

NB: as you can see, this only targets `list-0`, which is Quill's lowest list indentation level. If you want to tweak the counters for other indentation levels, you'll have to target `list-1`, `list-2`, etc.

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/alecgibson/pen/WNRmxVo).

Comment: I would like both numbered and alphabetical list in the toolbar. Is there a way to set that